# Meaning of “BesucherInnen”

Tags: meaning, gender, political-correctness

On a Viennese park sign, I saw the word “BesucherInnen”.  Is this a short form for *Besucherinnen und Besucher?*

Can this contraction be used generally, i.e., *…~Innen* covers both genders?

It seems to me like a form that only advertisements and similar use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it right - this form is called "[Binnen-I](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnen-I)", and it is used as a "neutral" form to cover both genders. It can be used generally in contexts where you are not bound to the "official" orthography rules, since it is not part of them.

Answer (score 9):

> The usage of the "Binnen-I" in german spelling occured from the 1980ies (e.g. *KollegInnen, MitarbeiterInnen*). It is frequently used but similarly often it is rejected. These short forms are not consistent with present spelling rules where capitals within words are not allowed.

<sup>Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the P.C. way, instead of using just "Besucher" (visitors), which traditionally encompassed both genders. Many people don't like it, but it's becoming more and more frequent. Personally I prefer "Besucher and Besucherinnen", instead of using the so-called Binnen-I.

Comment: Note that *Besucher* also covers both genders. (And in my personal opinion, wouldn’t some people insist on claiming something different, nobody would be offended by this anymore.)

Comment: Just as an aside... I find it weird when it's used with words for which the masculine plural does not end with the stem... like "FreundInnen" or "KollegInnen" or StudentInnen

Comment: Ich war überrascht, dass Du meinst, das Binnen-I werde häufiger, denn ich hätte es eher in den Achtzigern und Neunzigern verortet, siehe auch den Wikipedia-Artikel, auf den Matthias verweist, und den dort genannten Text von Ute Scheub. Dann fiel mir auf, dass Du wie auch die Frage aus Wien kommst. Ist dies vielleicht ein regionaler Unterschied?

Comment: Das ist gut möglich, hierzulande feiert es jedenfalls fröhliche Urständ. Als ArbeitnehmerInnenschutzgesetz hat es auch in der Gesetzgebung Einzug gehalten, und die Verwaltung in Wien ("progressive" Koalition Rot/Grün) verwendet es beinahe inflationär, etwa im Straßenverkehr ("... ausgenommen RadfahrerInnen" udgl.)

Comment: Solange sie nicht das Wort "MitgliederInnen" benutzen... (in den 80ern ab und zu gesichtet).

Comment: @Ingmar: Da breiten sich jetzt Passivformen aus, die natürlich im richtigen Sprachgebrauch eine andere Bedeutung haben, wie Zu-Fuß-Gehende. "Tot im Straßengraben liegen 3 Zu-Fuß-Gehende", das möchte man doch erst mal sehen!

Comment: @userunknown Nehmen wir mal an, die drei hätten sich durch nichts weiteres in ihrem Leben ausgezeichnet.- Dann würden da jetzt drei Lebende tot im Strassengraben liegen...

Comment: @tofro: Busfahrende müssen einen Führerschein der Klasse II und einen Personenbeförderungsschein haben. Oder doch nur Busfahrer?

Comment: @userunknown Oder sind die *Lebenden* im Strassengraben doch nur *Leber*?