# Does "StudentIn" (note capital "i") make sense?

Tags: gender

Today I've noticed that my friend's status on Facebook, when displayed in German, is "SchülerIn/StudentIn":

[image]

Two things are odd about this.

First he's male, and has his sex set accordingly - it displays as a "male" student in languages that distinguish between genders in this particular noun.

Second, why are the "i"s capital? Does this mean something special? If so, I'd assume it explains why a man's status would be displayed using the female form. Otherwise, I believe this is simply a translation mistake on Facebook's part?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The original question was "What is the Binnen-I?". This is  "Why is the Binnen-I used even in a *non*-generic context?"

Comment: It is a duplicate. It is used in a generic context too. Facebook does not respect a persons gender in translations of nouns, because in English "student" is a generic word that fits for both, male and female persons. If you want to assign something to German speaking users, that means exactly the same as the English "student", you would need 4 German nouns plus a conjunction: »Schüler, Schülerin, Student oder Studentin«. But is way too long. So you need to shorten it, and this what the Binnen-I was invented for. So you get: »SchülerIn oder StudentIn«. Without conjunction: »SchülerIn/StudentIn«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Diese Aussage ist sprachwissenschaftlich falsch. Schüler/Student sind im Deutschen auch generisch. Sogenannte Initiativen für geschlechtergerechte Sprache bestreiten das, aber gegen jede Evidenz. Da dies eine Sprachseite ist und keine politische Plattform, die Minderheitenpositionen propagiert, sollten persönliche Vorlieben m.E. mit der notwendigen Distanz vorgebracht werden.

Comment: @userunknown: Eine lebende Sprache verändert sich, und Wörter wie *Schüler, Student, Lehrer, Arzt, Mechaniker, Schneider* usw. sind gerade dabei, den generischen Status zu verlieren, und als rein männliche Wörter wahrgenommen zu werden. Das hat zwar gesellschaftspolitische Ursachen, ist aber trotzdem ein sprachliches Phänomen. Dazu kommt, dass solche Veränderungen vor allem von jungen Menschen vorangetrieben werden, also von genau jenen Menschen, die mit »student« bezeichnet werden. Daher ist gerade bei diesen Begriffen das Binnen-I sehr wohl ein geeignetes Mittel.

Comment: (Forts.:) Übrigens ist nach deiner Argumentation auch »Besucher« ein generisches Wort, daher behandeln http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15802/meaning-of-besucherinnen und diese Frage hier ganz genau dieselbe Fragestellung. Die hier gestellte Frage nach »SchülerIn/StudentIn« ist ein Duplikat der Frage nach »BesucherIn«. Und nur darum geht es jetzt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das ist aber kein Phänomen des unbewussten Sprachverständnisses sondern ein antrainiertes Missverstehen. Da das Binnen-I nicht durch Aussprache markiert werden kann (ohne das ganze Aussprachegefüge zu stören) stört es auch fundamental die sonst selbstverständlich gegebene Vorlesbarkeit von Texten. Des weiteren ist in Kompositionen wie *Wählerwanderung*, in Romanen (bis auf pol. motivierte Ausnahmen), in Lyrik u. Songtexten o. der Neuauflage alter Texte nichts von dieser Veränderung angekommen. Dass es in irgendeiner Altersgruppe mehr als 20% nutzen halte ich für eine Illusion

Comment: "Sind gerade dabei, den generischen Status zu verlieren" unterstellt, dass sie ihn in Zukunft verloren haben werden, als ob Du in die Zukunft kucken könntest. Seit 35, 40 Jahren wird versucht, die falsche Ideologie zu predigen. Nur aus schlechtem Gewissen von schlecht informierten Opportunisten wird dem Drängen einer lautstarken Minderheit von Extremisten, die nicht für die Mehrheit der Frauen sprechen, auch nicht der jungen, nachgegeben.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich widerspreche dir in keinem einzigen Punkt (außer eventuell bei den 20%, mag jetzt aber darüber nicht streiten). Trotzdem: Alles, was es über »SchülerIn/StudentIn« zu sagen gibt, trifft auch auf »BesucherIn« zu. Also: Duplikat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Und in dem Punkt widerspreche ich Dir nicht. :)